# Is documentation readable by non-programmers possible with Spock?

Tags: testing, specifications, spock, spock-reports

FitNesse has a wiki-style documentation feature. It provided both the code and the doc's for these specification tests.

Is there a way in Spock (with plugin? / out of the box?) to generate any type of similar documentation to show off to the project managers / stakeholders, who can not be expected to read the (Groovy) source code of the Spock specifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spock allows you to add descriptions to blocks, e.g.:

```
when: "5 dollars are withdrawn from the account"
account.withdraw(5)

then: "3 dollars remain"
account.balance == 3
```

While we don't use this information yet, it's easy to access from an extension (see link below). What's left to do is to turn this into a nice report.

https://github.com/spockframework/spock-uberconf-2011/blob/master/src/test/groovy/extension/custom/ReportExtension.groovy

Comment: I've been using the commenting feature and was wondering how that became a part of the output.  Thanks Peter!

Comment: Looks like NFJS took down the pps attachment that you had there. I'll do some googling on researching extensions & reports. Any add'l info you may be able to provide would be great.  Thanks again.

Comment: The GitHub repo I've linked to above contains all the material from my latest talk, including the slides.

Answer (score 11):

Well, I have used the Strings that describe each Spock block in your tests to generate HTML reports.
Please visit my project and let me know if that helps:

https://github.com/renatoathaydes/spock-reports

You can download the jar from the `reports` directory and then just add it to your classpath. Run your tests, and "miraculously" you will have reports generated in the directory `build/spock-reports`!

You can even provide your own CSS stylesheets if you want to customize the reports, as explained in README.

[Here's a blogpost](https://sites.google.com/a/athaydes.com/renato-athaydes/posts/writingspecificationsthatdoubleastestswithspock) I wrote about writing this Spock extension.

**UPDATE**

*spock-reports* has been available on [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.athaydes%22%20AND%20a%3A%22spock-reports%22) for a while now, as well as [JCenter](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/athaydes/spock-reports/).

Comment: UPDATE: you don't need to download the jar, spock-reports is available from JCenter as a maven artifact.

Comment: Hi There, I was wondering if there is a possibility to include console logs along with the spock reports. I am visualizing something like a expand button around when: then: tags and expanding these will display corresponding console logging if any. Also, I would like to contribute to this if it is possible to implement and moved to GIT.

Comment: please use [Github](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/spock-reports) for feature requests.

Answer (score 0):

There are some great answers in here already, but if you want to keep your BDD definitions free from any plumbing whatsoever, you can take a look at [pease](http://pease.github.io/), which will let you use Gherkin specification language with Spock.

Comment: Unfortunately [pease is now unmaintained](http://pease.github.io/2015/10/06/unmaintained.html):

_Pease is outdated and won't be further developed or maintained. My recommendation is to have a look at the cucumber-jvm project._